# What is the role of the @ symbol in c++?

Tags: c++, preprocessor, m4

I saw some code in glog like below:

```cpp
#if @ac_cv_have_libgflags@
#include <gflags/gflags.h>
#endif

@ac_google_start_namespace@

#if @ac_cv_have_uint16_t@      // the C99 format
typedef int32_t int32;
typedef uint32_t uint32;
typedef int64_t int64;
typedef uint64_t uint64;
#elif @ac_cv_have_u_int16_t@   // the BSD format
```

What is the role of the @ symbol in c++, how to use it?

Comment: That is not standard C++

Comment: The names between the '@' characters refer to template arguments with some code generation tool, for instance CMake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those "@ac...@" tokens are for `autoconf` aka `./configure`.  They are replaced before the file is compiled, by the preprocessor called `m4`.

After the `m4` preprocessing is done on your example, but before the C preprocessing is done, it might look like this:

```
#if 1
#include <gflags/gflags.h>
#endif

namespace google {

#if 1      // the C99 format
typedef int32_t int32;
typedef uint32_t uint32;
typedef int64_t int64;
typedef uint64_t uint64;
#elif 0   // the BSD format
```

Some of the tokens in your example are populated by a file like this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/open-vcdiff/+/0a58c5c2f73e5047b36f12b5f12b12d6f2a9f69d/gflags/m4/google_namespace.m4

For more on `autoconf`, see: [http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~sedwards/presentations/autoconf1996.pdf](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Esedwards/presentations/autoconf1996.pdf)

Comment: The link http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~sedwards/presentations/autoconf1996.pdf is dead. Typo? Intresting: I can open the link from my comment but not from your post. Some "special" chars inside... No idea :-)

Comment: @Klaus: The link works fine for me, both in your comment and in my answer.  No idea why it doesn't work for you, if you really want to know I guess you could open up Developer Tools in your browser or use Wireshark or something.

Comment: I see a difference in encoding of the '~' character. As I copy the link in some editor on my pc it is displayed as: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Esedwards/presentations/autoconf1996.pdf. Something between OS, encoding, charsets, UTF vs windows vs ... Simply forget about :-)